# Inserting objects into a list, c++

Tags: c++, list

I am trying to create a list in c++ that contains geometric data.   The list is a list of triangles:

```
class Triangle
{
public:
Triangle(Point P1,  Point P2,  Point P3);
Triangle(const Triangle& T);
~Triangle() {delete e1; delete e2; delete e3;}



const Triangle operator=(const Triangle & T);

bool InCircle(Point & P);
int TriNumber() { return TriangleNumber;}
void SetTriNumber(int trinum) { TriangleNumber = trinum;}
Edge ReturnEdge(int i);
Point ReturnPoint(int i);





protected:
Point p1,p2,p3;
Edge *e1, *e2, *e3; 
int TriangleNumber;             
};
```

However, when I try to create a list of triangles, I get a segmentation fault using the following lines:

```
const Point p1(100.0, 100.0);
const Point p2(-100.0, 100.0);
const Point p3(0.0, -150.0);



Triangle TT(p1,p2,p3);

list<Triangle> trilist;
list<Triangle>::iterator iter;
iter = trilist.begin();
// the next line is causing all the problems:
trilist.insert(iter, TT);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact error you get? A stacktrace from gdb would be helpful.

Comment: what does your ctor look like?

Comment: Show the definitions of the default and copy constructors, as well as the assignment operator (which by the way has the wrong signature).

Comment: const Triangle operator= should be Triangle& operator=

Comment: Beginner's C++ Tip: "If you're using `delete`, You're Doing It Wrong."

Comment: Could you elaborate on that a bit @KerrekSB?  Assuming user* is newing e1/2/3 in the ctor, why wouldn't he want to delete them in the dtor?

Comment: @JoeFish: I wouldn't `new` up anything, either. There's usually a much better way using non-dynamic members, worst-case resource-managing classes.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that STL containers make *copies* of the objects you put into them. (See "Effective STL" by Scott Meyers, Item 3.)

If your objects don't implement copying properly, you will get segmentation faults at best, and subtle bugs at worst, when you put them into containers. (As Meyers notes, "Copy in, copy out. That's the STL way.")

Since your objects seem to imply that dynamic allocation goes on somewhere, I would guess that a copy constructor, assignment operator, or destructor for one of your classes is not implemented properly.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your implementation of the copy constructor and the assignment operator it's likely that Edges `*e1, *e2, *e3` are being deleted more than once.

Can we see the implementation of those to confirm?